# Save div as image file in vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

I want to save div element as an image file using VueJS. I tried using canvas. How can I convert and save div element as an image file?

Comment: Did you try to save image as png using Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com) :

JS :

```js
html2canvas(document.querySelector("#capture")).then(canvas => {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
});
```

HTML :

```html
<script src="html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<div id="capture" style="padding: 10px; background: #f5da55">
  <h4 style="color: #000; ">Hello world!</h4>
</div>
```

`html2canvas.min.js` need to be in your website :

> All the images that the script uses need to reside under the same origin for it to be able to read them without the assistance of a proxy. Similarly, if you have other canvas elements on the page, which have been tainted with cross-origin content, they will become dirty and no longer readable by html2canvas
>   **Source:** https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation

Answer (score 2):

There is a wrapper for vue.js to use html2canvas easier within vue:
https://github.com/mycurelabs/vue-html2canvas

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.